# Python 3 using an if statement to read the values in 1 array and append another value to another array

Tags: python, arrays, if-statement

I am new to Python and trying to write a program that reads the integer values stored in the array (percent) then based on there value using an if statement append a string to the array (grade).

The code seems to be reading the array (percent) but not storing the correct value in the (grade) array. I can't seem to find an answer that solves the problem. Here is my code

```
percent = [33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99]
grade = []

for i in range(0, len(percent)):
    if i >= 70 and i <= 100:
        grade.append("Grade A")
    elif i >= 60 and i <= 69:
        grade.append("Grade B")
    elif i >= 50 and i <= 59:
        grade.append("Grade C")
    elif i >= 45 and i <= 49:
        grade.append("Grade D")
    else:
        grade.append("No grade achieved")

print(grade)
```

All that is prints out is "No grade achieved" even though the values do not match that. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You are comparing the *index* against the intervals, not the *values*. Use ``for i in percent:`` instead.

Comment: Also, you don't need to check the second half of those statements, e.g. `and if i <= 69`. You already know it has to be 69 or less if it gets to that `elif` block, otherwise it would have entered the previous `if` block instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're comparing i, your loop counter to your grade validator.

You want the loopcounter to say which item of the array to call out.
So if i = 0 in one instance, it's looking to see if 0 is greater than 70 and less than 100.
If i = 5, and you're calling percent[i], you're getting the sixth value in the array percent, 88.

```
percent = [33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99]
grade = []

for i in range(0, len(percent)):
    if percent[i] >= 70 and percent[i] <= 100:
        grade.append("Grade A")
    elif percent[i] >= 60 and percent[i] <= 69:
        grade.append("Grade B")
    elif percent[i] >= 50 and percent[i] <= 59:
        grade.append("Grade C")
    elif percent[i] >= 45 and percent[i] <= 49:
        grade.append("Grade D")
    else:
        grade.append("No grade achieved")

print(grade)
```

Answer (score 1):

While other authors have contributed correct answers, I'd like to take a moment and introduce you to a different approach that will be "better". In general, in programing the more "if/if else"s you have, the exponentially complex the logic.  If you have 1 "if" there are two branches. 1 if + 1 else, 4 branches, etc. So it is in general a good idea to minimize branching. You can refactor the situation to use a look up table which carries several advantages:

1. It can be loaded from an externally supplied table (Database).
2. Minimal code changes if you want to add, remove, or modify the items in the table.
3. The same logic is applied for each, cutting down on special cases, but making special cases much more obvious.

Example:

```
grade_scale = {45: 'Grade D', 50: 'Grade C', 60: 'Grade B', 70: 'Grade A', 0:'No grade achieved'}
student_percents = [33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99]
letter_grades = []
for student_percent in student_percents:
    for percent_grade in sorted(grade_scale.keys(), reverse=True)): #sorted makes sure the table is read int he right order, regardless of key order (0 comes after 70 in the example), but python will sort keys in ascending order anyway for some datatypes. 
            if (student_percent >= percent_grade)
                letter_grades.append(grade_scale[percent_grade])
                break
```

Answer (score 0):

```
percent = [33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99]
grade = []

for i in range(0, len(percent)):
    if percent[i] >= 70 and percent[i] <= 100:
        grade.append("Grade A")
    elif percent[i] >= 60 and percent[i] <= 69:
        grade.append("Grade B")
    elif percent[i] >= 50 and percent[i] <= 59:
        grade.append("Grade C")
    elif percent[i] >= 45 and percent[i] <= 49:
        grade.append("Grade D")
    else:
        grade.append("No grade achieved")

print(grade)
```

You were comparing the values against the index of i rather than the percent element at index i. So you were going vs values 0,1,2,3, etc.

The above code works as intended

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the value of `i` is the index of your loop, and not the value of `percent`. Consider this change:

```
percent = [33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99]
grade = []

for i in percent:
    if i >= 70 and i <= 100:
        grade.append("Grade A")
    elif i >= 60 and i <= 69:
        grade.append("Grade B")
    elif i >= 50 and i <= 59:
        grade.append("Grade C")
    elif i >= 45 and i <= 49:
        grade.append("Grade D")
    else:
        grade.append("No grade achieved")

print(grade)
```

A few notes:

1. You can check the value of `i` using the debugger, or by printing `i` within the loop.
2. You could instead keep your loop definition the same (`for i in range(0, len(percent))`) and check the value of percent `percent[i]` within your if/else statements.

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding array values with its index. What i is giving you is an index of each element of the array, not the actual value.
Change each condition as

```
percent = [33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99]
grade = []

for i in range(0, len(percent)):
    if percent[i] >= 70 and i <= 100:
        grade.append("Grade A")
    elif percent[i] >= 60 and i <= 69:
        grade.append("Grade B")
    elif percent[i] >= 50 and i <= 59:
        grade.append("Grade C")
    elif percent[i] >= 45 and i <= 49:
        grade.append("Grade D")
    else:
        grade.append("No grade achieved")

print(grade)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write `for i in range(0, len(percent)):` you are iterating over the **indexes** (hint: `i` stands for index) of the *list* (that's how we call them in python, not arrays, since they work differently than what for example C(++) calls arrays).

So, when you check for the value of `i` you are not checking 33, then 44, then 55 etc, you are checking 0, then 1, then 2...

There are two ways to get the correct value.

1. Use the index to look into the list:

   `if percent[i] >= 70:`
2. Instead of iterating over the indexes of the list, iterate over the list's elements:

   `for x in percent:`